# N-Count Days For Changing Dates For Ecommerce Shipment Sheet

Tags: excel

I have to submit a daily MIS for orders which are Undelivered For less then 2 Days, Undelivered Between 3-5 Days and 5+ Days.

Currently i'm doing this manually by counting from the Purchase Date forward. So e.g. for an order of 11th March, i'll just count 2 days till 13th (If undelivered) and type 1 in front of the column and do a count manually of all orders outstanding in each column.

The problem arises as the column descends and the dates get further and further away from current day.

This is tiresome but i can't seem to find an algorithm that can do this automatically.

Can anyone help please.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this screenshot:

[image]

Cell A1 has the date you want to compare to. Don't user the Today() function, since it is volatile and can slow down the workbook. Just manually put in the desired date.

The formula in cell E2 is

```
=IF(D2="undelivered",IF($A$1-C2<=2,"less than 2",IF($A$1-C2<=5,"3 - 5 days","5+ days")),"")
```

In words: if the status is "undelivered", calculate the difference between purchase date and A1. If it is less than 2, return that text, if it is less than 5, return that text, otherwise return the third text.

Copy that formula down.

In cells G3 to G5 you see each of the three texts and next to it is a formula. Starting in H3

```
=COUNTIF(E:E,G3)
```

copied down to H5.

Your layout may differ, so you will need to adjust the formulas accordingly.